# managing some hybrid app behaviors in connectiong and using wifi

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I need to do something with wifi in ionic!

first of all , I should be able to turn wifi on when the app runs , after that I have to get the active access points list and finally choose one of them to connect. how can I do that in ionic???

Answer (score 0):

So you can use this plugin to check the status of the network connection. You can check the wifi status through that and then start your app. For the access points list and connection to them through the app ionic or any OS doesnt not allow that. It's upon the user's choice which they select.
Hope that answer's your question.

Comment: which plugin do you mean

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/